# File Function in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi im new at python(i have been learning it for like 3 days) and for your help will be thankful.

So i made this function which u see below , created 2.txt documents called oldfile,newfile. To the oldfile i wrote 64 characters(like "asasdasffafdsfsfgsgsdgS"). The function should open both files and write to the new file 50 characters from the new file but when i press start in pyscripter the code works but it doesnt do anything(It wont write anything to the newfile.txt).

```
def copy_file(oldfile, newfile):
    infile = open(oldfile, 'r')
    outfile = open(newfile, 'w')
    while True:
        text = infile.read(50)
        if text == "":
            break
        outfile.write(text)
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
    return
```

Comment: have you called your function????

Comment: you code is correct, it working just call the function

Answer (score 0):

you need to call your function:

```
def copy_file(oldfile, newfile):
    infile = open(oldfile, 'r')
    outfile = open(newfile, 'w')
    while True:
        text = infile.read(50)
        if text == "":
            break
        outfile.write(text)
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
    return

copy_file('old_file_name_path', 'new_file_name_path')   # call your function with path of file here
```

Comment: you using windows or linux??

Comment: Thank you for the response but it still gives me an error something is wrong with my path. Could u please write there the exact path if both files are on located on desktop?